# Read updated configurations from application.properties without repackaging the uber jar

Tags: java, quarkus

Is there a way to read the updated changes in application.properties without repackaging the jar in Quarkus? I could not find anything related in the official documentation at https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference. So I am assuming that the uber jar has the application properties built in. So is there a way to override those configs while running the jar?

Edit: What I mean by overriding is: Is there a way to specify the path of the config file that the jar reads while running the jar. Something similar to `java -jar app.jar -DConfig='/path/to/application.properties'`.

Comment: What configuration do you want to override?

Answer (score 1):

In Quarkus some of the configurations are fixed at build time, (the once in the documentation with the lock). Others are not, this ones you can change them at runtime using several methods, for example, using environmental variables or properties in the launch commands.

Check this links for more information:
https://quarkus.io/guides/config#build-time-configuration
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources

As you can see in the configuration-source section, quarkus will firstly search in system properties and other sources rather than in the application properties file, there is one possibility for you to change the value of your properties.

Comment: I'd especially highlight this config source: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#application-properties-file AFAIK, its path is not configurable, but other than that, it's exactly what @rightjoin asks for.